# How to make navbar go from transparent to solid bootstrap 5.1

Tags: html, jquery, css

Been trying this for a while now and finally given up. Trying to make the navbar transparent to a colored background when scrolling down the page. I'm using bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
.your-navbar {
  background: rgba(100,50,70,0.5);
}
```

where **100,50,70** is rgb color, and **0.5** is opacity (transparency) value

Comment: Sorry need forgot to add for when I scroll down the page

Comment: Then use `javascript window.onscroll = function(){ /* here, add this class to your element */ }`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem you mentioned. I hope that will be useful.

For example...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
      $('.home .x-navbar').css({
         'background-color': '#ffffff'
      });
      $('.home .x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a').css({
         'color': 'red'
      });
      $('.home .x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', '//jadoreweddingsalgarve.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/wine.png');

   } else {
      $('.home .x-navbar').css({
         'background-color': 'transparent'
      });
      $('.home .x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a').css({
         'color': 'green'
      });
      $('.home .x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', '//jadoreweddingsalgarve.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/logo2.png');
   }

});
```

Or;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $('.navbar').css('background', 'red');
   } else {
      $('.navbar').css('background', 'transparent');
   }
});
```